# Obtain Gmail cookie value

Tags: php, gmail, cookies

is there a way to obtain gmail's cookie value. Particularly I would like to know logged users email.

Comment: Are you trying to mine email addresses?

Comment: Because if you are, bears will eat you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot read gmail's cookies. Cookies are restricted by domain.

That having been said, you can use [OpenID](http://openid.net/) to allow a user to log into gmail and get their email address after.

Answer (score 5):

No. Cookies are only accessible from their own domain. For obvious security reasons.

Comment: But what if I really really really want to read someone else's email?

Comment: Find out where they live, break in, and hope they left their computer logged in to their mail provider.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  In Firefox, you can go to Tools->Privacy->Remove Individual Cookies.  From there you can browse to the Google cookie folder.  My cookie name "GAUSR" had my email address in it.